# Como iniciar um serviço?

Tags: c#, .net, jar

A função abaixo inicia através de um arquivo .jar um WebService.

```
private static void StartService()
{
    try
    {
        var FileStart = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), @"WSOPaf.jar"));
        Process.Start(FileStart.ToString());
    }
}
```

É necessario colocar a extenção do arquivo ".jar" ou apenas o nome?

Essa é a melhor maneira de abrir o serviço?

Comment: Você consegue "rodar" esse jar manualmente? Como espera que essa execução seja feita?

Comment: Esse serviço inicia automaticamente no windowns, mas se ele não iniciar, preciso que inicie com outro programa que criei, nesse programa essa função é a responsável.